# laravel error messages not display after first redirection

Tags: php, laravel, validation, redirect

If the incoming request parameters do not pass the given validation rules, I redirect the user back to the previous page.
Even though validation error messages exist in session, they aren't displayed after first redirect.
When i refresh page again the error message are displayed.

```
Blade
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
      </ul>   
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
@endif




Controller    
public function index()
{
    $this->validation();
    $perpage = request()->input('perpage',10);
    $perpage = $perpage<10 ? 10 : $perpage; 

    $musics = Music::where('title','like','%'.request()->input('title').'%')->paginate($perpage);

    $page = request()->input('page',1);
    $page_count = intval(ceil($musics->total()/$perpage));
    if($page < 1 || (!empty($page_count) && $page > $page_count)){
        return redirect(request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['page' => 1]));
    }

    return view('admin.musics.index',
        [
            'musics'=>$musics,
            'perpage'=>$perpage,
            'page'=>$page,
            'page_count'=>$page_count
        ]);
}

private function validation()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
        'title' => 'nullable|max:255',
        'page' => 'numeric|min:1',
        'perpage' => 'numeric|min:10|in:10,20,30,50,100,200,300,500,1000'

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
    }
}
```

for example, in first image,as you see parameter `perpage` that should be one of the numbers 10,20,30,50,100,200,300,500,1000 is 22, so error happens, error message exist in session but it isn't displayed!

[image: image first]

In second image, I correct the parameter `perpage` and refresh page, now error is displayed!

[image: valida]

---

I realized that `redirect` did not work.
When validation fails, redirection doesn't work!
Why it happens?
my route rules is :

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){

    Route::get('musics','MusicsController@index');

});
```

I changed `return back()` to `return redirect()->back() and return Redirection::back()` , but it doesn't work!
What's the problem?
The point is I use one page (I mean it's not like insert action that I have two method, create method and store method, I don't want to submit form to middle page and then return).

Comment: use ```return redirect->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();``` instead of ```return back()->...```

Comment: @ajafari I changed but the problem did not fix.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return Redirect::back()
->withErrors($validator)
->withInput();
```

Comment: I changed but the problem did not fix.